# Django testing of views.py and model.py

Tags: python, django, testcase, web-api-testing

I am new to django testing am doing the testing for my views.py file which cintain alot oif classes
Here we are take one of the class among the others
the views.py file looks like

```
class AssignSubFarmer(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    http_method_names = ['patch', 'post']
    serializer_class = BatchSerializer
    queryset = Farm.objects.all()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': request.headers['Authorization']}
        farm_id = request.data.get('farm_id', None)
        batch_id = request.data.get('batch_id', None)
        subfarmer_id = request.data.get('user_id', None)
        mobile = request.data.get('mobile', None)
        name = request.data.get('name', None)
        document_photo = request.data.get('document_photo', None)
        user_type = request.data.get('user_type', None)
        aadhar_number = request.data.get('aadhar_number', None)
        pancard = request.data.get('pancard', None)
        voter_id = request.data.get('voter_id', None)
        gst_no = request.data.get('gst_no', None)
        primary_user_id = request.data.get('primary_user_id', None)
        if not subfarmer_id:
            payload = {
                "name": name,
                "mobile": mobile,
                "document_photo": document_photo,
                "user_type": user_type,
                "aadhar_number": aadhar_number,
                "pancard": pancard,
                "voter_id": voter_id,
                "gst_no": gst_no
            }
            response = requests.post(url=settings.CREATE_SUB_FARMER.format(primary_user_id), data=json.dumps(payload),
                                     headers=header)
            data = json.loads(response.content)
            secondary_user_id = None
            if not data['error'] and data['data']:
                secondary_user_id = data['data'].get('secondary_user_tbl_id', None)
            else:
                return Response({"message": data['message'], "error": data['error']}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            subfarmer_id = 0
            if secondary_user_id:
                subfarmer_id = secondary_user_id
            if farm_id and subfarmer_id:
                Batch.objects.filter(farm_id=farm_id).update(sub_farmer_id=subfarmer_id)
            elif batch_id and subfarmer_id:
                Batch.objects.filter(id=batch_id).update(sub_farmer_id=subfarmer_id)
        elif farm_id:
            Batch.objects.filter(farm_id=farm_id).update(sub_farmer_id=subfarmer_id)
        elif batch_id:
            Batch.objects.filter(id=batch_id).update(sub_farmer_id=subfarmer_id)
        return Response({"message": "Successfully updated", "error": "False"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

and when I am doin the testing for this class
in test_views.py file

```
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from igrow.urls import *
from farm_management.models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import json


class TestAssignSubFarmer(APITestCase):

    def test_assign(self):
        sample = {"farm_id": "123", "batch_id": "1222",}
        response = self.client.get(reverse('assignsubfarmer'),sample)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

In terminal when I give the test command

```
python manage.py test test_model.py
```

It shows an  error

```
UserWarning: The default behavior of S3Boto3Storage is insecure and will change in django-storages 2.0. By default files and new buckets are saved with an ACL of 'public-read' (globally publicly readable). Version 2.0 will default to using the bucket's ACL. To opt into the new behavior set AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None, otherwise to silence this warning explicitly set AWS_DEFAULT_ACL.
  warnings.warn(
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_model (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_model
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_model'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

[This Picture shows the directory of files that are arranged in this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpjrX.png)

Comment: U can correct me because I am not much aware of django testing, So if am using the wrong testing method please do correct me

Comment: python manage.py test <<app_name>>

Comment: there are multi management folders inside the app of project like inaisde apps there are farm, batch, crop and each have there own test model views etc please jhave a look the picture that i  have mentioned above

Comment: Yes I do the same , here firm_management should be an app. so you may run the tests only for this app like this : python manage.py test firm_management

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your file is named `test_models.py` and you're calling `test_model.py` (in singular).

Here's official documentation on [how to run only one file / specific testcase / specific test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests).

For your particular case, I would try running `python manage.py test farm_management.test.test_models` (this is just a guess based on docs, I didn't actually check that).

---

On a related note, it looks like you're using Pycharm. It has a builtin mechanism for running tests, so you don't have to manually type in the dotted path every time you want to run a specific test. It allows you to run a specific test, or the whole testcase, and looks like this:

[image]

Comment: yes... I think I have not written the testing code properly that's why it's not responding properly

Comment: Hey, It's a request can you please vote up
for this question 
It will help me to earn a badge